# AS3. Unable to connect SWF with PHP in order to process a flashvar

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

here 5:44 am , all night up trying to make this work.

Im trying to send a URL from a swf file to a php file, process that URL with the php code and return it to the swf.

I succeeded on sending and procesing the data. The problem arrives when I try to use the data on the actionScript code.

```
//videoSrc is a string containing the URL I want to process.
videoSrc=modifySrc(videoSrc);

function modifySrc(vSrc:String):String{ 
    // Assign a variable name for our URLVariables object
    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    // Build the varSend variable
    // Be sure you place the proper location reference to your PHP config file here
    var varSend:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://foo.net/config_flash.php");
    varSend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    varSend.data = variables;
    // Build the varLoader variable
    var varLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
    varLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
    varLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

    variables.uname = vSrc;
    variables.sendRequest = "parse";    
    // Send the data to the php file
    varLoader.load(varSend);

    // the php function ends with ' print "var1=$UrlProcessed"
    function completeHandler(event:Event):void{
        vSrc = event.target.data.var1;
    }

    return vSrc;
}
```

The problem is that vSrc never changes. I think the problem is related to this line:
    `varLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);`

I'm not being able to make completeHandler modify vSrc value.

Answer (score 1):

That's because network requests are asynchronous. The return value from `modifySrc` remains unchanged while the function is executing. It only changes when the `URLLoader` instance triggers a `Event.COMPLETE` event. Try this instead:

```
modifySrc(videoSrc);

function modifySrc(src:String):void
{
    ...
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, modify_completeHandler);
    ...
}

function modify_completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var loader:URLLoader = event.target as URLLoader;
    loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, modify_completeHandler);

    videoSrc = loader.data.var1;
}
```

I've truncated the rest of your initialization code from modifySrc for brevity.

Comment: I tried using that code but didn't work. videoSrc still doesn't change it's value.

Is there any way to wait until the loader ends in order to asign videoSrc new value? 

videoSrc can be modified directly form inside a function?

If needed I can post the whole code

Comment: Well, you have to wait for the loader to end. That's the whole point of separating the two functions and not returning the value of videoSrc from the modifySrc function. Happy to provide more guidance if you wish.